# Installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, 20.04

Will the files inside my windows 7 get deleted when I install Ubuntu 20.04 version?

Comment: Depends on which options you use during your install.  It's best in my book to assume yes, and have a decent backup, which you'll likely never use after creation, but you may find yourself very sorry if you don't create it.  Any shrinking of partitions is dangerous (any minor of move is to that data, a change to drive partitioning involves loads of moves and potential just for corruption of metadata which can cause dataloss.. better safe than sorry)

Answer (score 2):

You should always consider the possibility of data loss, especially when you are making changes to partitions or adding/removing operating systems.  Always make backups!

If you install Ubuntu instead of Windows 7, everything on Windows 7 will be deleted.

If you install Ubuntu *alongside* Windows 7, the data should be retained.

FYI: Windows 7 reached End Of Life in January 2020.  This OS is no longer safe to use and must be replaced with an operating system that still receives security updates.

Answer (score 1):

It depends! If you are replacing Windows 7, Then yes! If you are dual booting, Then no!